# Attaching image using ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an app, where i'm generating an image using EditText field(  **textArea.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); textArea.buildDrawingCache(true);** ) and saving it on SD card. And at the same time i wanted that image to be shared between other apps using ACTION_SEND intent. Here the problem i'm facing is i'm able to generate the image from EditText but the same image is not getting attached to the intent(**share intent** in this example), please tell me where i'm going wrong..

Thanks in advance..

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File picDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/myPic");

        if (!picDir.exists()) {
            picDir.mkdir();
        }
        textArea.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        textArea.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = textArea.getDrawingCache();
        Date date = new Date();
        String fileName = "img" + date.getTime() + ".png";
        File picFile = new File(picDir + "/" + fileName);
        try {

            picFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream picOut = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
            boolean saved = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                    picOut);

        if (saved) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Image saved to your device Pictures "
                                + "directory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +picFile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Send picture using:"));

            } else {
                //Error
            }
            picOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textArea.destroyDrawingCache();
    } else {
        //Error

    }
```

Comment: "But some how its not working for me" -- this is a completely useless description of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I am using for attaching files to an email :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.lorem));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{emailto});
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.lorem));
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.send_mail)));
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the image is on internal app cache directory.

Comment: file on app directory canot be accessed from another application.If you should share something with third party application,you must write your own content provider.