# android - how to add to intent an internel stored image?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have mange to store on my app imges files.

the directory path that contains the images is -

```
/data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
```

now what im want to do is to add the relevent image to an intent - 
so i have used the next code for the text parts -

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with ?"));
```

But i don'tunderstand how can i add an image file-
by the way i have an option to get the full path of the image, but i sure don't understand how to add it to intent - so thanks for any kind of help

Let me try it clear it a bit -
if let's say  i want to add the image to an e-mail - could it be enough to add to intent the image uri on the memory?!? and if so, what should i add to tne intent than, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646240/attaching-image-using-action-send-intent. try searching on so. you will find similar post. Is the image in internal phone memory?

Comment: yes it's at the internal phone memory

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal. files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user)(unless phone in rooted)

Answer (score 1):

maybe to pass the whole image,you can do it just like passing objects of classes
then you will have to use parceable  and all that which will be very tedious for you,but instead of sending the whole image(which may be very big sometimes)you can just pass the url of the image and fetch the url on  the other activity and operate on it.It's a more efficient way to do it....

if you really want to pass the image you can convert the image into it's byte code using bitmapdecodefactory and send it,and then convert it back again....

Comment: so let's say i want to add the image to an e-mail - that's what u think i need to do?

Comment: lol ok, so  you know how to send objects of a class that you have created??suppose you have a class called xyz,which has 2 data types,say string and bitmap,i can provide you an answer which may work in that case,but i am not sure if the same method will work only  for Bitmap...

Comment: here is an idea,you can create a class which extends Bitmap,and implements parcelable and use that instead of bitmap..is that ok for you?if yess i can provide you the code after that

Comment: the thing is,i have never worked with email,but i do know what how to send and receive data of  datatypes which are not provided by android

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on sending a very small image (kilobytes) I would actually recommend against sending images this way.  It's usually better to simply send the URI or file system path, and allow the caller to retrieve the image that way.

Place it in the "extras" or similar within the intent you plan on sending.

If you plan on using internal storage (versus external images or media paths on the SDCard) you'll most likely want to create a ContentProvider / ContentResolver that other applications can use to get those image files from your sandboxed protected storage for your app.